# Execute function using value of list as parameter

Tags: python, list, dataframe, function

I have a function that has a parameter requiring a value, and I have the values stored within a list. (These values are the index numbers of a dataframe; the dfFunction takes a row from the dataframe using iloc, so a number between 0 and 99 is needed for the function to return a value).

Such as

```
IndexList = [0,1,2,3,4,...,99]
RowIndex = IndexList.index(0)
dfFunction (RowIndex)
#Output: 10
```

But I'd like to be able to run through the list of index values and apply them to the function, thus producing the function result for each index number.

However, the code I have at the moment, to iterate through the list, is returning `<function __main__.IndexFunction()>`

```
def IndexFunction():
    RowIndex = 0
    while RowIndex <= len(IndexList):
        RowIndexValue = IndexList.index(RowIndex)
        RowIndex += 1
    return RowIndexValue
```

I thought I could apply this function as the parameter, like: `dfFunction(IndexFunction)` but I also know this isn't correct.

Is there a while loop or way to apply enumerate() or something else so I can use the list values in the dfFunction and produce the results for all of them?

Ideally:

```
dfFunction(#insert solution)
#Output dfFunction results for each list index to put back in dataframe as a new column
```

OR:

```
IndexList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,...,99]

IndexNumber = 0
row_index = IndexList.index(IndexNumber)
Result = dfColumn1.iloc[row_index] / dfFunction(row_index) 
Result 
#Output

IndexNumber = 1
row_index = IndexList.index(IndexNumber)
Result = dfColumn1.iloc[row_index] / dfFunction(row_index) 
Result 
#Output

IndexNumber = 3
row_index = IndexList.index(IndexNumber)
Result = dfColumn1.iloc[row_index] / dfFunction(row_index) 
Result 
#Output

etc
```

Simplified so there doesn't have to be 100 repeats of those chunks of code, so one function spits out all the outputs in one go, like:

```
#Output of function from Index Position 1
#Output of function from Index Position 2
#Output of function from Index Position 3
#Output of function from Index Position 4
```